# TD overlaps footer on long content and added no page break

Tags: html, css, laravel-livewire, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

dompdf generates the table, footer, and header correctly and all page breaks are fine. I have a td with very long text. When creating the PDF, the text overrides the footer.

How to make that not override in the footer and go to the next page?